# Blending Two Images by edge with CI or GPUImage

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, core-image, gpuimage

Is it possible to blend 2 images by edges like this with GPUImage or Core Image ?
http://www.ephotozine.com/article/photoshop-tutorial--blending-two-photos-together-16158

I need to "connect" images by edges but want them to blend :) is it possible? I was searching in documentations of boths for correct filter but cant find anything suitable

Answer (score 0):

For Core Image, it's `CILinearGradient` and `CIBlendWithMask`.  If you look in the Core Image programming guide or the WWDC videos there's a tilt shift example that shows basically how to do this.

I would only apply the gradient to the top layer as opposed to both like they do in the tutorial (that's how I would approach it in Photoshop, too; when you do it to both layers it's easy to wind up with some undesired transparency in the middle).

When you create your linear gradient, don't just have set your points to opposite ends, instead you want to start it at one edge and end it just past the edge, like this:

Set inputPoint0 to (1, 0)
Set inputColor0 to (0,1,0,1)
Set inputPoint1 to (.9*width, 0)
Set inputColor1 to (0,1,0,0)